# App search results not showing up in spot light iOS

Tags: ios, search, ios9, corespotlight

I implemented `App Search` using `CoreSpotLight` framework. The results are still not showing up in iOS spotlight

The approach i followed is

1. Created `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` with `title`, `keywords` and `contentDescription`
2. Created `CSSearchableItem` with above created attributes set.
3. Added the `CSSearchableItem` to `CSSearchableIndex`

Every thing seems to be correct, not sure why the results are not showing up..

Comment: 1) Update your question with relevant code. 2) What device are you testing on? Make sure `CSSearchableIndex isIndexingAvailable` is true.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, i managed to find the solution. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36786712/3733561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to find the issue,

The simulator ( iPad Retina 9.3 ) which i was using,  is not supported for core spotlight. We can find the unsupported devices names in [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/index.html?utm_1)

> Although app search is available for iOS 9 users, the search functionality of NSUserActivity and Core Spotlight is not supported on iPhone 4s, iPad 2, iPad (3rd generation), iPad mini, and iPod touch (5th generation).

Also,
The following code was throwing an error

```
[[CSSearchableIndex defaultSearchableIndex] indexSearchableItems:@[item] completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error :%@",error);
        }
 }];
```

The log is  `Error : Error Domain=CSIndexErrorDomain Code=-1005 "(null)”`, which means `CSIndexErrorCodeIndexingUnsupported` , Indexing isn't supported on this device.
Hope this save time for someone.

**Edit**

As @rmaddy suggests, check for `CSSearchableIndex isIndexingAvailable`, this straightaways help to find the issue.

Comment: This is why you need to call `CSSearchableIndex isIndexingAvailable` to make sure your app is running on a supported device.